# How to create a auto hide scroll bar in swing application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In my swing application i would like to create auto hide scroll bar but default scroll bar displaying with scroll bars help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Show your attempts. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What are the conditions by which the scroll bars should hide?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-hide? The default scroll bar for `JScrollPane` should _only_ be visible when needed. Are you sure you're using `JScrollPane` instead of `JScrollBar`?

Comment: it is visible even if i entered jus one data

Comment: @peeskillet am using jscroll pane only

Comment: What is the scroll pane wrapping? And are you still using GUI Builder?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the scroll bar should be visible only when it expands but by default it is visibling eventhough there is no data in the list

Comment: @peeskillet for my design purpose still am processing with gui builder onle

Comment: @Suresh Actually, The `JScrollPane` by default, hides it's scroll bars...

Comment: @Suresh you have to set the scroll bar policy to "AS_NEEDED" for the horizontal and vertical scroll bars..

Comment: From the design view, in the navigator pane, select the JScrollPane and go to the propterties window. Make sure the property `verticalScrollBarPolicy` and `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` are set to `AS_NEEDED`

Comment: @Jayaprasad yeahthat only am trying to do but i dint find such method can u tel me how to set that policy

Comment: @peeskillet already it is fixed as AS_NEEDED but it is visible still i deleted all the records too but its visible only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane();
sPane.setAutoScrolls(true);
sPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
sPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

But by default the scroll pane hides its scrolls.

Comment: By default it is fixed as AS_NEEDED but still the scroll is displaying and even scrolling without any records

Comment: @Suresh try setting autoscrolls to true

Comment: Tried that too. I was worked with .net the same thing before in vs if list extends then the scroll will be appeared but in swing by default its displaying automatically even there is no records in the list

Comment: Try setting the scroll explicitly through code to AS_NEEDED.

Comment: i tried explicitly its still displaying